# Dradis Framework error in Kali Linux. Error :bundler: command not found: rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, git, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried installing Dradis framework on Kali Linux,my testing operating system.I have followed the instructions given here[Git Repo for Dradis](https://github.com/dradis/dradis-legacy) and after executing

```
ruby bin/setup
```

it created separate folders for each framework and then when executing the next command

```
`bundle exec rails server`
```

the installation file broke and gave an error.

```
bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Later i checked my rails environment and it gave me this..

```
> RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/test/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.1.0
     - /home/test/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/games
```

I even tried this link correspond to same error[Error Link in Issues](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2291) but the result was same.Is there any way i can completely remove rails from my Kali Linux and re install it again and update it.

Comment: https://github.com/dradis/dradis-ce this is newer version

Answer (score 0):

Dradis committer here, first thing that comes to mind is that you're using the old repo, and not the new one.

Old:
https://github.com/dradis/dradis-legacy

New:
https://github.com/dradis/dradis-ce

Then make sure to run `bundle install`.

Also, check the official [Install from Git guide](http://dradisframework.org/documentation/install_git.html).

Answer (score -1):

Did you run

```
bundle install
```

? This will install all the gems specified in the Gemfile, which includes installing Rails.

```
bundle exec rails server
```

should work after that